# Data exploration analysis within R code and nycflights13 package

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to see all flights that happen every single day and where they go to. I am ultimately stuck, I have selected the categories that I want selected use the filter to try to get all the flights that have exactly 365 flights but it says there is no data, I don't know what my next step should be.

```
flights %>% 
  select(month, day, flight, carrier, origin, dest) %>%
  filter(sum(flight) == 365) %>%  
  view()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)
require(nycflights13)


flights %>%
  select(month, day, flight, carrier, origin, dest)   %>% 
  group_by(flight, carrier, origin, dest)             %>% 
  mutate(n_flights = n())                             %>%  
  ungroup                                             %>%  
  filter(n_flights == 365)                            %>% 
  head 

# 
# month   day flight carrier origin dest  n_flights
# <int> <int>  <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <int>
# 1     1     1    371 B6      LGA    FLL         365
# 2     1     1     59 AA      JFK    SFO         365
# 3     1     1    219 B6      JFK    CLT         365
# 4     1     1   1357 AA      JFK    SJU         365
# 5     1     1    407 VX      JFK    LAX         365
# 6     1     1    251 VX      JFK    LAS         365
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This uses `summarise` instead  of `mutate`. You can edit to your own grouping variables.

```
library(nycflights13)
flights %>% 
  select(month, day, flight, carrier, origin, dest) %>% 
  group_by(carrier,flight,origin,dest) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(N=n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(N)) %>% 
  filter(N==365) %>% 
  View()
```